# How to use weather API and JSON data to determine if the current time is day or night (android)

Tags: android, json, api, time, weather

im working on a weather app as a personal project and i like it to be more customized by displaying different backgrounds depending weather its day or night 
so my JSON data includes the following :
"sunrise":1588042810,"sunset":1588090464
is it possible to use this data to determine sunrise and sunset times and compare it with system time to determine ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(sunRiseTimeStamp);
int h = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);        // get minutes 

Calendar calendar2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();//current date
if (h == calender2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) && m ==  calendar2.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
 //do something , it is sunrise 
else
 //do something else
```

Comment: what is the sunRiseTimeStamp ?

Comment: they are the values you got.